# Typoscript: Get image path of fe user associated image

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to show informations of a single Fe user with typoscript. Everything is working fine except I can't get the image path. How can I get the path to the associated image?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Noël

EDIT:
Hi, I'm using TYPO3 version 9.5.21.
The TS code to get the fe user data:

```
lib.feUserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
    table = fe_users
    select {
        pidInList = 16
        max = 10
        orderBy = last_name DESC
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = username
        10.typolink {
            parameter = 483
            additionalParams.dataWrap = &user={field:uid}
            useCacheHash = 1
        }
        10.wrap = |</br>
        20.### here I'd like to get the image path###
        }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? show your typoscript/ fluid/ php code. What TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: edit your question. as you can't put code in a comment

Comment: Do you use FLUIDTEMPLATE for your website template integration?

Comment: Yes, I'm using FLUIDTEMPLATE

Comment: I don't think you want the image path, but a clean `image` (or `picture`) tag. So you need an `IMAGE` object. in typoscript or an image viewhelper in the FLUID template.

Comment: do you want to show the  user objects in a specific page or do you want to have the data  everywhere?

Comment: On a specific page: I have a page which lists all users, after click on a single user it shows the details of the selected user. I'll try to do that with a GET variable with the ID of the fe_user that passes to the typoscript code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypoScript you can use the objects FILES and IMAGE in order to get an image, you can try something like this I guess :

```
lib.feUserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
    table = fe_users
    select {
        pidInList = 16
        max = 10
        orderBy = last_name DESC
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = username
        10.typolink {
            parameter = 483
            additionalParams.dataWrap = &user={field:uid}
            useCacheHash = 1
        }
        10.wrap = |</br>
        
        20 = FILES 
        20 {
            references { 
                table = fe_users 
                uid.data = {field:uid} 
                fieldName = image 
            } 
            renderObj = IMAGE 
            renderObj { 
                file.import.data = file:current:originalUid 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```